Print Pixel in a console platform independant
I made a TextArt using █ (full block) characters and want to use it for a Game Project of mine.

Sadly, when I try to print it, I get either undefined behavior (it outputs ª instead of █), or no output.
I am using the Unicode character set and std::wcout. I am not sure if Unicode is correct here.
I am also not sure if I should use wchar_t for the pixel art or just a normal char*.
const wchar_t* MainMenu = L"..."  // pixelart using full blocks
                          L"..."
                          L"...";

std::wcout << MainMenu << std::endl;

I tried to wcout.imbue UTF-8 to check if just the interpretation was wrong, but that gave me even weirder output.
I also tried to convert it to multi-byte, but since I try to make this console game OS-independent, I can't use windows.h or WideCharToMultiByte().
I even disabled deprecation for this to try codecvt with its wstring and wstring_convert. Still no correct output :(
Last of my tries was using wcstombs_s(), which was unsuccessful because of an error:
char mbstr[sizeof(MainMenu)];
wcstombs_s(mbstr, MainMenu, sizeof(mbstr));
std::wcout << mbstr;

The error says MainMenu is not a wchar_t*.
Codeium's explanation:

The issue is that the second argument MainMenu is a wide character string, but wcstombs_s expects a source wide character string, and it seems like MainMenu is not a wide character string. The source wide character string should be a pointer to the first wide character in the wide character string, but in this case, MainMenu seems to be a wide character string literal.
To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that the second argument MainMenu is a wide character string, and you may need to convert it to a wide character string before passing it to wcstombs_s.


Probably easier to find a TUI library.

Looks like you are looking for something like ncurses.

"Last of my tries was using wcstombs_s(), which was unsuccessful because of an error ... The error says MainMenu is not a wchar_t*." - it is a wchar_t*, and that is actually a problem, because the way you use sizeof(MainMenu) does not yield the correct value for the array size you want. You would need to use wcslen(MainMenu)+1 instead.  But then you can't declare mbstr[] statically since Variable-Length Arrays are not standard C++, so you would need to use std::vector or std::string instead.

but would that fix the problem @Remy-Lebeau. Would std::cout take the converted Multibyte Character string and print it successfully to the console...

@morigan all you can do is give the data to the console. The console decides how to display it. On some platforms (ie Windows) your code can set the charset of the console to match your data. But that is not portable to all platforms.

how do i find out which charset supports what characters and which charsets are supported by both windows and ie Linux? Any good artikels?
